# Windows app POSTMAN "Could not get any response" but Chrome app works fine

Tags: rest, jira, postman, jira-rest-api

I have a JIRA REST API endpoint I want to make a call out to. From the Windows POSTMAN app I get the following error:

```
There was an error connecting to https://jiraurl.com/rest/api/2/issue/a123.
```

However if I use the Chrome app POSTMAN same URL it works just fine. With the chrome app i can make the request without any headers and i get a response. With the Windows app I've tried several different auth headers without any luck.

I'm assuming it has something to do with certs or the fact that in chrome i'm already logged in to the JIRA instance and so no further authorization is required I just can't figure out what settings or headers i could be missing.

The reason why I'm trying to figure out if the windows app is because i'm writing a c# program and i'm getting the same error so i know it's not necessarily a POSTMAN issue.

Comment: The chrome web app will be configured with your chrome proxy settings, the windows app will use the Windows proxy settings I believe. Verify that the Windows network proxy settings are correctly configured. As this may be the potential cause of your issue

Comment: Check this Link for Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49009808/5152146